# ListView OnItemClickListener not being triggered in bottom sheet

Tags: java, android

I have created a bottom sheet using the newly updated support library. Basically, whenever an item in my recyclerview is long-clicked, a bottom sheet is shown (containing a linearlayout which contains a listview). But whenever I tap the items in the listview nothing happens. I added toasts and it is never triggered when I tap on the sheet items. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here is the listview initialization method:

```
public void initSheet() {
        bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.list_sheet);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_sheet_row, getSheetInfo(), "Sheet");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_sheet_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setHideable(true);
    }
```

Here is the recyclerview long click:

```
@Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                final String itemText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textRow)).getText().toString();
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "sdjakfjs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, itemText);
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share the item"));
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("New", itemText));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                editText(itemText, position);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                listAdapter.deleteItem(position);
                                break;
                        }
                        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    }
                });
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
```

Comment: Please make sure what exactly you using, list view or recycler view. your code is of list view and at some places you use recycler view

Comment: Like I said in the op I have a recyclerview as the main app, but have a listview in the bottom sheet

Answer (score 0):

try this.
implement custom clicklistener it will work pefectly.

```
// creating interface to handle clicks for Recycler view items
public interface ClickListener
{
    void onClick(View view,int position);
    void onLongClick(View view,int position);
}
public static class CustomRecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;
    public CustomRecyclerTouchListener(Context context,final RecyclerView recyclerView,final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener)
    {
        this.clickListener=clickListener;
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
               View child=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                if(child!=null && clickListener !=null)
                {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child,recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View child=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
        if(child!=null && clickListener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent))
        {
            clickListener.onClick(child,recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {
    }
}
}
```

Then implement like this.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomRecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            User user=users.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user.getName()+" is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            User user=users.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user.getName()+" is long clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
```

For more details refer here:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: I already am using this for the recyclerview. The issue I am having is with the listview. Sorry if I was not clear. Essentially I have a listview inside of a bottomsheet which is not receiving the click commands for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I ended up doing was creating 4 textviews inside of the linear layout instead of using the listview. Then I just added an onclick listener for all of the textviews to do their respective commands